# Force NULL to be a string in SELECT NULL FROM Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sqldatatypes

I am migrating some views and finally returning null for some columns for backward compatibility. However, when I change the column name to `NULL AS [MyName]`, the column becomes an `INT`.

How to force the [MyName] column to stay a `String`?

```
SELECT NULL AS [MyName] 
FROM [Table]
```

This is for SQL Server.

Comment: Give this a try --> SELECT Convert(varchar(10), NULL) as MyName

Comment: This seems to work. You can give it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work.

```
SELECT Convert(varchar(10), NULL) as MyName
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like below :

```
SELECT cast(NULL as varchar(100)) AS [MyName]
```